# MongoDB Convert sigle object to array of object based on key:value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, aggregation-framework

Is there a way by using mongodb queries, convert a sigle object field to an array of object but key:value based?

**Before**

```
"fields" : {
    "field1" : 1,
    "field2" : true, 
    "field3" : false, 
    "field4" : "any string value"
}
```

**After**

```
"fields" : [
    {
        "name" : "field1",
        "value": 1
    }, 
    {
        "name" : "field2", 
        "value" : true
    }, 
    {
        "name" : "field3",
        "value" : false
    }, 
    {
        "name" : "field4",
        "value" : "any string value" 
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) in an aggregation pipeline:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "fields": {
        "$objectToArray": "$fields"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ksmfLTGPwzd)